# NameError: global name 'enterFilePath' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI using python. I am using Tkinter library and python 2.7.

My aim is to get the path that I browse to and insert it as a string in the Entry box which somehow I am not able to do and I am getting the error as mentioned in the title above.

Below is my code snippet:

```
def browseSWPath(self):
    #global enterFilePath
    self.frameTwo = Frame(self.mainFrame, width=640, height=100, bg='white')
    self.frameTwo.pack(side='top', expand=False, fill='both')

    self.swFlashPath = Button(self.frameTwo, text='SW Flash Path', command=flashFile)
    self.swFlashPath.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5, anchor='nw')
    #self.swPath = StringVar()
    self.enterFilePath = Entry(self.frameTwo, bd=2, width=75)
    self.enterFilePath.pack(side='left', pady=10, anchor='nw')

def flashFile(): 
    pathName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if pathName:
        enterFilePath.delete(0, END)
        enterFilePath.insert(0, str(pathName))
```

Traceback:

[image]

Comment: please show the actual and complete error.

Comment: And what is this `enterFilePath`? Seems.. not defined.

Comment: `enterFilePath` is part of a class(which one, we have no idea). So you need `class_instance_name.enterFilePath` to use it. (assuming `flashFile` is not part of that class since it has no `self` parameter)

Comment: The error you pasted an image of ("enterFilePath is not defined"), and the error in your question ("pathName is not defined") are different. Which one is the real problem?

Comment: I removed some noise from your question body but haven't touched wrongly(?) indented part. Please correct that indentation.

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry, corrected now..i was trying something else on the code that time! apologies

Comment: @Lafexlos: corrected now

Comment: are you aware that `enterFilePath` and `self.enterFilePath` are not the same thing?

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for that tip..resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

As *@bryanOakley* said in the comments above that **self.xx and xx are not the same thing**. For those who are looking for an answer to the question, there were two changes that made it worked.

1. Removing self from *self.enterFilePath*
2. in the line *enterFilePath.delete(0, Tkinter.END)*

Thanks a lot!